# How do I insert a language-tagged literal using a SPARQL INSERT DATA query?

Tags: label, sparql, sesame, rdfs

I have a problem with a query in SPARQL for a Sesame triplestore.
I enter this query in "SPARQL Update" option of the Sesame workbench:

```
INSERT DATA { <http://www.example#test> rdfs:label "test_label"@en }
```

I would have this RDF result:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example#test">
     <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">test_label</rdfs:label>
</rdf:Description>
```

But I don't know how write the query in order to add `xml:lang="en"`.

With my query, I have this error:

```
org.openrdf.query.UpdateExecutionException: org.openrdf.sail.SailException:
org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: Expected ':', found ' '
```

I don't manage to find the right syntax for my query.

Comment: As it stands your question is unanswerable, you haven't shown the code you use to execute this update so we can't reproduce your problem.  Please provide a minimal complete example, you can use the **edit** button under your question to add more details

Comment: I reworded my question. I hope that it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPARQL update query as you have it is correct. The error is caused by a bug in Sesame release 2.7.11 (see [SES-2063](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-2063)).

A fix will be available in the next patch release. In the meantime, a workaround is to reformulate your query, as follows:

```
 INSERT { <http://www.example#test> rdfs:label "test_label"@en } WHERE {}
```